# Undefined variable in CodeIgniter view 5

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am learning CodeIgniter and I got stuck on this error.
`$categories` is fine, but when I want to see `$nationality` I have an error

> Message: Undefined variable: nationality
>
> Filename: pages/add_recipe.php

add_recipes.php

```
<?print_r($categories);?>
<?print_r($nationality);?>
```

My controller

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller
    {    
    public function add_recipe($page = 'add_recipe')
            {
                $this->load->helper('url');

                if (!file_exists('application/views/pages/' . $page . '.php')) {
                    show_404();
                }
                $this->load->model('Categories_model');
                $data['categories'] = $this->Categories_model->get_categories();

                $this->load->model('Nationality_model');
                $data['nationality'] = $this->Nationality_model->get_nationality();

                $this->load->view('templates/header');
                $this->load->view('templates/nav');
                $this->load->view('pages/' . $page, $data);
                $this->load->view('templates/sidebar', $data);
                $this->load->view('templates/footer');
            }
    }
```

Models

```
public function get_nationality($conditions=null,$limit=null,$offset=0,$order=null){
        if($conditions!=null){
            $this->db->where($conditions);
        }
        if($order!=null) {
            $this->db->order_by($order);
        }
        $query = $this->db->get('nationality',$limit,$offset);
        return $query->result();
    }

public function get_categories($conditions=null,$limit=null,$offset=0,$order=null){
        if($conditions!=null){
            $this->db->where($conditions);
        }
        if($order!=null) {
            $this->db->order_by($order);
        }
        $query = $this->db->get('categories',$limit,$offset);

        foreach($query->result_array() as $row ){
            if(!$row['parent_id']){ 
                $data[$row['id']][] = $row['title']; 
            }else {
                $data[$row['parent_id']]['sub'][$row['id']] = $row['title']; 
            }
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

Comment: When you are showing your code in "models", the two methods are in two separate model files right ? `get_nationality()` in your `model_path/Nationality_model.php` and `get_categories()` in your `model_path/Categories_model.php` ?

Comment: Yes, they  are in two separate model files

Comment: Just an idea, what happens if you switch the names?

Comment: the names of model files?

Comment: I suspect that the request from the table 'nationality' returns an empty array , but can not understand why... the table in the database is full

Comment: @JennyJam - if it returned an empty array you would not get a undefined error, it would just show an empty array. What i was suggesting would be `$data['nationality'] = $this->Categories_model->get_categories();` and the same with `$data['categories'] = $this->Nationality_model->get_nationality();` just to see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the help , I found the problem!

Comment: @JennyJam - What was it?

Comment: it turned out that the page is called from another controller , confused with the names

Answer (score 0):

```
Can you please update the Nationality model function get_nationality with this, try it...

public function get_nationality($conditions=null,$limit=null,$offset=0,$order=null){
        if($conditions!=null){
            $this->db->where($conditions);
        }
        if($order!=null) {
            $this->db->order_by($order);
        }
        $query = $this->db->get('nationality',$limit,$offset);
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: thanks, I tried what you recommend , and have tried it before, but it does not solve the problem

Comment: Can you please check the $data array "print_r($data);" on controller function before $this->load->view('templates/header');

Comment: Nothing happens when I check so, but in view <?print_r($categories);?> shows an array and <?print_r($nationality);?> causes an error

Comment: Either try in controller file:
Replace this:
$data['nationality'] = $this->Nationality_model->get_nationality();
with
$res = $this->Nationality_model->get_nationality();
echo $res; die('here');
$data['nationality'] = $res;

Comment: Thanks for the help , I found the problem!

Comment: Let's the other know about your problem and write an answer please !

Answer (score 0):

it turned out that the page is called from another controller , confused with the names